# grok filtering pattern issue

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I try to match the loglevel of a log file with a grok filter, but still getting a _grokparsefailure. The problem is maybe with the space between [ and the log level.

example of log: 2017-04-21 10:12:03,004 [ INFO] Message

my filter:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "log.level" => "\[ %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried some other solutions without success:

```
"\[ *%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]"
"\[%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]"
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The point is the default field is message and you need to match all the string

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logDate} \[ %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]%{GREEDYDATA:messages}"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No you don't have to match the whole string, a partial match work.

Comment: @baudsp what's mean, i paste you example and put in grok debugger it works .... what's you means about partial match work

Comment: If the user want to retrieve just one part of the string (here the loglevel), matching the full string is useless; it can be done with matching just the relevant part (here `\[ %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]`). Both our solutions work, I just prefer mine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the option `match` in your filter: this option is a hash that tells the filter which field to look at and which field to look at.

Your regex is fine (you can check with http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), the issue is with the field name; it should be `message`.

So in your case, your filter should look like this:

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => "\[ %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]"
    }
}
```